# Track User Activity Entry and Exit point in WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress

Anyone help me How to track visitor activity on WordPress site

User Entry point and Exit point.
Also, track form submission

Comment: Why just not use Google Analytics. If you need to see the data in WP - you can use some plugin for integration (ex. https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-dashboard-for-wp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Analtyics for this. Is you set up an tracking code you can see where your users enter the site, and on which pages users leaves.

About the from submission you can use event tracking in google analtyics. You can manually set it up. Or use tag manager.

Comment: Hi @zarex360

Yes, we have already used google analytics code but I need to track manually or using WordPress plugin 

Now, I am using *WassUp* WordPress Plugin [https://wordpress.org/plugins/wassup/] this plugin show the user entry and exit point.

I requesting you to please share some similar plugin or custom method so that we can integrate for the same.